# Can this polyomino tile the toroidal grid?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid, tiling, polyomino

Inspired by certain puzzles on *Flow Free: Warps*.

### Background

We all know that L-triominos can't tile the 3x3 board, and P-pentominos can't tile the 5x5 board. But the situation changes if we allow the board to wrap around in both dimensions:

#### L-triominos can tile 3x3 toroidal grid

The 3rd tile wraps around through all four edges.

```
┌ ┌─┐ ┐
  │ │3 
┌─┤ └─┐
│ │2  │
│ └─┬─┘
│1  │  
└───┘ ┘
```

#### P-pentominos can tile the 5x5 toroidal grid

The 5th tile wraps around through all four edges.

```
┌ ┌───┬─┐ ┐
  │   │ │
┌─┘   │ └─┐
│  1  │2  │
├─────┤   │
│  3  │   │
│   ┌─┴─┬─┤
│   │   │ │
└─┬─┘   │ ╵
  │  4  │5
└ └─────┘ ┘
```

Note that, in both cases, wrapping around in only one dimension doesn't allow such tiling.

In case the Unicode version is hard to read, here is the ASCII version:

```
3 2 3
1 2 2
1 1 3

5 1 1 2 5
1 1 1 2 2
3 3 3 2 2
3 3 4 4 5
5 4 4 4 5
```

### Challenge

Given a polyomino and the size (width and height) of the toroidal grid, determine if the polyomino can tile the toroidal grid. The polyomino can be flipped and/or rotated.

A polyomino can be given in a variety of ways:

- A list of coordinates representing each cell of polyomino
- A 2D grid with on/off values of your choice (in this case, you *cannot* assume that the size of the grid defining the polyomino matches that of the toroidal grid)

The output (true or false) can be given using the truthy/falsy values in your language of choice, or two distinct values to indicate true/false respectively.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

The polyomino is given as the collection of `#` symbols.

#### Truthy

```
# (singleton, a.k.a. monomino)
5x7 (or any size)
--------
## (domino)
4x3 (or any even size)
--------
#
## (L-triomino)
3x3 (as shown above)
--------
##
### (P-pentomino)
5x5 (as shown above)
--------
##
 ## (Z-tetromino)
4x4 (left as an exercise to the reader)
--------
###
#
# (V-pentomino)
5x5
--------
####
   #
   ### (a polyomino larger than the grid is possible)
4x4
--------
###
  ###
    ### (single polyomino can cover the entire grid, and can wrap multiple times)
3x3
```

#### Falsy

```
## (domino)
3x5 (or any odd sizes)
--------
###
#
1x8
--------
# #
### (U-pentomino)
5x5
```

Comment: Nice challenge. I find the ASCII art hard to read, could you add the alternative of having `1`, `2`, `3`, etc as each of the `#` shapes given in the two corresponding examples?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I added a pure ASCII version of the top two examples, though I doubt I understood your request correctly. (Or do you want something like [this](https://tio.run/##S07MK0ss/v9fAQiUucAkiAJjZS4gVObiArJAIspgCqIILAnGClBZsBiSAjD//38A)?)

Comment: what you posted is perfect, thanks

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>300</s> <s>265</s> 163 bytes

*-35 bytes after suggestions from @xnor, @ovs, and largely @user202729 (removing evenly divisible check allowed for a one-liner + lambda)*

*-102 bytes following encouragement + general suggestions by @user202729*

```python
lambda l,w,h:all(w*h-len({((e-(p&4)*e//2)*1j**p+p/8+p/8/w*1j)%w%(1j*h)for e in l for p in c})for c in combinations(range(8*w*h),w*h/len(l)))
from itertools import*
```

Takes input as a list of complex coordinates of each cell of the polyomino. Outputs False for Truthy and True for Falsey (quirky de Morgan optimization).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##XVLtbusgDP3PU1hU2yBji/ox3apS7ot0@8Ey2nBHgAtEaTTt2TsgS5cuErZzfOzjxNghNEavzsfq@ax4@/rGQbGeNTuuFOmL5kEJTT4IEQ/E3m5oIcpyRYvlv6Kw97bcplP28Z3e9Dckwg09GAcCpAYFKbQprD8zXOfYtK9S8yCN9sRxfRRkW0QlyqIpk5yilKKDMy3IIFwwRnmQrTUuFOeae@Ghgj1aQHBdaIYYEIxxdIvo2BP7Q9kMy@CGrSM4QmiE1hma8bL5bvF0YS/QpcXmmp8LflR/BFIKAEYzL57SKOMpPeWnYQ5ceTH8nn49nydKJmzJtrnCN67T7xAMiJOouyDgfyfrdzWgqQW6fNWKoheU9uDThvMu0t/c5Ul85R@9VTIQ/Kwx3S93LxlX1X4MUuHAlNR5uUJ3rXA8COLp2GDinFjdcHfNSVUzWnrkARKvqvACX2ey6iO3Vug3crof0u3KBOukDnF4uGN3DPpv3zDA1V/M4EjyzaXnLw) with many testcases. Since this brute-forces, I have commented out a few cases to run fast enough for TIO.

Thoroughly commented:

```python
lambda l,w,h:
    all(                        # we want any configuration to work, but De Morgan gives any(L==len) <==> not all(L!=len) <==> not all(L-len)
        w*h-len(                      # if two polyominos in a configuration overlap, then there are duplicate cells
                                    #   so the length of the set is less
                {                   # create a set consisting of each possible position+orientation of L/len(l) polyominos:
                    (                   # here, e is a single cell of the given polyomino
                        (               # reflect e across the imaginary axis if p >= 4 (mod 8)
                            e-          # e-e.real*2 = e-e//.5 reflects across the Im axis
                            p&4             # Only reflect if the 2^2 bit is nonzero: gives 4* or 0* following
                            *e//2           # floor(z) = z.real when z is complex, so
                        )                   # e//2 (floor division) gives z.real/2 (complex floor division only works in Python 2)
                        *1j**p          # rotate depending on the 2^0 and 2^1 bits. i**x is cyclic every 4
                        +p/8              # translate horizontally (real component) by p>>3 (mod this later)
                        +p/8/w*1j           # translate vertically (im component) by p>>3 / w
                    )%w%(1j*h)          # mod to within grid (complex mods only work in Python 2)
                    for e in l      # find where each cell e of the given polyomino goes
                    for p in c      # do this for each c (each set of position+orientation integers)
                }
        )
        for c in combinations(           # iterate c over all sets of w*h/len(l) distinct integers from 0 to 8*L-1
            range(8*w*h)              # each of these 8*L integers corresponds to a single position/orientation of a polyomino
                                    # Bits 2^0 and 2^1 give the rotation, and 2^2 gives the reflection
                                    # The higher bits give the position from 0 to L=w*h-1  ==> (0,0) to (w-1,h-1)
            ,w*h/len(l)        # w*h/len(l) is the number of polyominos needed since len(l) is the number of cells per polyomino
                                    # can't switch to *[range(8*w*h)]*(w*h/len(l)) because Python 3 does not allow short complex operations as above
        )
    )
from itertools import*
```

A new 169-byte solution that replaces `combinations` with recursion:

```python
g=lambda l,w,h,k=[]:all(g(l,w,h,k+[((e-(p&4)*e//2)*1j**p+p/8+p/8/w*1j)%w%(1j*h)for e in l])for p in range(8*w*h))if w*h>len(k)else len(set(k))-w*h
from itertools import*
```

This has the advantage of removing `combinations` (12 characters on its own) and one for loop, but the self-invocation takes many bytes. Currying would not save length.

Comment: Because of the weird way Python handles complex mod, you can actually do `e%w%(1j*h)` in place of `(e.real%w,e.imag%h)`.

Comment: `k-k.imag*2jfor ...` is 2 bytes shorter than `k.conjugate()for ...`. (Or `2*k.real-k for ...` at the same length)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for all the suggestions! I ended up being able to reduce many nested comprehensions (the `sum(p,[])`'s sole purpose was to undo a nest, and `range(8*L)` combines 3 loops), so string-replace-exec became unnecessary. I'm not sure what your last comment does because it reflects the translation, not the whole polyomino, but I think it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @user202729 Oh, I reasoned out that `/8j` would work because it's just a vertical shift in the opposite direction, but complex divisor also changes it to normal division instead of floor division. It would be great if there was a way to distribute out the p/8 somehow

Comment: Fixed (same number of bytes after using `combinations`)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 233 bytes

Takes input as `(w)(h)(p)`, where \$p\$ is a binary matrix describing the polyomino. Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

Similar to my original answer, but uses a more complex expression to update the cells of the matrix instead of explicitly rotating the polyomino.

```javascript
w=>h=>g=(p,m=Array(w*h).fill(o=1))=>+m.join``?(R=i=>i--?m.map((F,X)=>(F=k=>p.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>k|=v?m[Z=i&2?p[0].length+~x:x,~~(X/w+(i&1?Z:W))%h*w+(X+(i&1?W:Z))%w]^=1:0,W=i&4?p.length+~y:y))&&k)(F()||g(p,m)))|!o||R(i):0)(8):o=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDRboJAEEXf/Qr7UJzRlbKtTZpNBtIXPsA00UhpJFZhFViCViQh/jouIba0MWkyDzt3zt47u9vgGOxXucwO41R9rusN1QXZEdkhQcYSes3zoIRiGKG5kXEMijgi2aPE3CqZLpcOTEmSLcdjJzGTIANw2VwD4NKO7KyVclZqKW@bIzvpZlfR0Um8BUnj0ck8yzfjdRoeotH5JE7sfIb5QzECaXBnIWaI99FQt/NWmYmFVgr/g7iw2ExbTJzs@34pSkTD2CG4gFUVNs9AxOpOVdUUJAoL4QWFIqteqXSv4rUZqxAG3lv@dYhKf4C9rr6BJ2zK6/X7Hvd7Pv6dP2NT7ZxxZvnseryJTzp2t4luYMeuRX@xg/fUc4N4/8/Wt2N48w8/e/NrkKUzG7y@AA)

---

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>311 ... 252</s>  250 bytes

Takes input as `(w)(h)(p)`, where \$p\$ is a binary matrix describing the polyomino. Returns a Boolean value.

Not quite as desperately long as I was expecting. :p

```javascript
w=>h=>g=(p,m=Array(w*h).fill(o=1),P)=>+m.join``?[...13**7+''].some(i=>(p.sort(_=>i-7).map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>(P[x]=P[x]||[])[y]=v),P=[]),m.map((F,X)=>(F=k=>P.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>k|=v?m[~~(X/w+y)%h*w+(X+x)%w]^=1:0))&&k)(F()||g(p,m))),p=P,!o)):o=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9Ba4NAEIXv@RXpIXFGN1uXtKQExtCLZw89BLbbRtIkmqgrmmoE6V@3igRsSSkMy5udb9@bPfqFn2@zMD3PEv2xa/bUlOQE5BwIUhbTc5b5FZRmgHwfRhFoEsg8JMeK@VGHyWazkpxzMTfNhWUYiuc63kFIDqStzM7wTk44WyCP/RQgY1X7NOubgl3aBjx5UdQddS0VykpR0SZQq1ncgy5bd6BLJ3K8P41ONRWrWH59wfq@tCqcBGZpwdq64KRUbySWNuJ0ekJwAev60P0OEVlKHrvTiEtNdrPVSa6jHY/0AQz5kn2eg0oZOBre72GOXcnReCyFGin8PX/Ervo5E8xW7Cpv4g8Du9vEMHBg16M/WOM1ka4f5f9sfTtGIDwN9hbXILvN7PDmGw)

#### How?

The following code builds all possible transformations \$P\$ of the polyomino \$p\$:

```javascript
[...13 ** 7 + '']         // this expands to ['6','2','7','4','8','5','1','7']
.some(i =>                // for each value i in the above list:
  ( p.sort(_ => i - 7)    //   reverse the rows of p[], except when i = '8'
    .map((r, y) =>        //   for each row r[] at position y in m[]:
      r.map((v, x) =>     //     for each value v at position x in r[]:
        ( P[x] =          //       transpose p[y][x]
          P[x] || [] )    //              to P[x][y]
        [y] = v           //
      ),                  //     end of inner map()
      P = []              //     start with an empty array
    )                     //   end of outer map()
    (...)                 //   more fun things happen here!
    p = P,                //   get ready for the next transformation
    !o                    //   success if o is cleared
  )                       //
)                         // end of some()
```

We use a flat array of \$w\times h\$ entries to describe the matrix. All of them are initially set to \$1\$.

The function \$F\$ inserts the polyomino in the matrix at the position \$(X,Y)\$ by XOR'ing the cells. It returns \$0\$ if the operation was done without setting any cell back to \$1\$.

```javascript
F = k =>                  // expects k undefined for the first call
  P.map((r, y) =>         // for each row r[] at position y in P[]:
    r.map((v, x) =>       //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
      k |=                //     update k:
        v ?               //       if v is set:
          m[~~(X / w + y) //         toggle the value at (X + x, Y + Y),
            % h * w +     //         taking the wrapping around into account
            (X + x) % w   //
          ] ^= 1          //         k is set if the result is not 0
        :                 //       else:
          0               //         leave k unchanged
    )                     //   end of inner map()
  ) && k                  // end of outer map(); return k
```

For each position \$(X,Y)\$ in the matrix:

- We do a first call to \$F\$. If successful, it is followed by a recursive call to the main function \$g\$.
- We just need to call \$F\$ a second time to remove the polyomino -- or to clear the mess if it was inserted at an invalid position.

Hence the code:

```javascript
F(F() || g(p, m))
```

The recursion stops when there's no more \$1\$'s in the matrix (success) or there's no more valid position for the polyomino (failure).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>120</s> 115 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷＳ⊞υ⌕Ａι#≔⟦⟧ζＦθＦηＦ²«≔ＥθＥη⁰εＦＬυＦ§υμ¿λ§≔§ε⁺κν﹪⁺ιμη¹§≔§ε⁺ιμ﹪⁺κνη¹Ｆ²Ｆ²⊞ζ↨⭆⎇μ⮌εε⪫⎇ν⮌ξξω²»≔…ζ¹υＦυＦζＦ¬＆ικ⊞υ｜ικ⁼⊟υ⊖Ｘ²×θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJLb8IwDD7TX2HBJZEyaVTcOAHbJKbB0MZt2qGjhkSkKSQNBab99s4p5aFdFilx7M/@/EgWMrGLPNFVNTYbX0x99oWWbXk/utUl6aVUGoHV5vfCKrNinMPMO8m8gCdl0oHWTAlod9qc/AfOqZVhH58CjqQucwvEC7WUjYw5fEetxnOSbNhWQBBSwD3nApACW7XnC5pVQZl4EzkoxibFfUidkU0tgWkOJ6YzdpYoYKa9Y2sBJrBO8tTrnNU2FeIFSNpd3gfUDv9hqSP@sNTMF5am5PjaZD2lo4Bh4pCdhhfanKM1iT2wTMAb7tASiHXXAp5zZS64ueJ7wsIuQwlxmPPPedKjw0LjSOabkKlLsD@P3TeVHBs5zQs2VEWpHA5MGjpa85u3bKBX2yD9aEYVF@xx6xPt2IwyeKJ/wIXFDE2BKdlK@iaxgLnK0IVnlDysflX1ol7UoRUBwOmge3W3078) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order width, height, newline-terminated polyomino and outputs a Charcoal boolean i.e. `-` only if the polyomino tiles the torus. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the size of the grid.

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⌕Ａι#
```

Input the polyomino and convert it to a list of horizontal indices.

```
≔⟦⟧ζ
```

Start building up a list of polyomino placements.

```
ＦθＦηＦ²«
```

Loop through each vertical and horizontal offset and direction.

```
≔ＥθＥη⁰ε
```

Start with an empty grid.

```
ＦＬυＦ§υμ
```

Loop over each cell of the polyomino...

```
¿λ§≔§ε⁺κν﹪⁺ιμη¹§≔§ε⁺ιμ﹪⁺κνη¹
```

... place the optionally transposed cell in the grid, but offset by the outer indices.

```
Ｆ²Ｆ²⊞ζ↨⭆⎇μ⮌εε⪫⎇ν⮌ξξω²
```

For each of four reflections of the grid, push the grid to the list of placements, represented as a base 2 integer (e.g. a grid with just the bottom right square filled would be 1 etc.)

```
»≔…ζ¹υＦυ
```

Start a breadth first search using the first placement.

```
Ｆζ
```

Loop over each placement.

```
Ｆ¬＆ικ
```

If this placement does not overlap the grid so far...

```
⊞υ｜ικ
```

... then push the merged grid to the list of grids.

```
⁼⊟υ⊖Ｘ²×θη
```

Check whether we pushed a completed grid. (This must be the last entry because any incomplete grid must by definition have fewer polyominoes and would therefore have been discovered earlier.)